# Reactjs and material-ui library import error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I've got a quick question. I have react and all included but I want to import component from a material-ui library and the path is all good but it cannot find the module.

My code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

var Comp = React.createClass({
 render(){
    return(
      <p>aa</p>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
 <Comp />,
 document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Just a base code.

This is the error in the console:

```js
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider"
    at webpackMissingModule (App.js:57)
    at Object.<anonymous> (App.js:57)
    at __webpack_require__ (App.js:20)
    at App.js:40
    at App.js:43
```

And that is files folder:

[image]

So, what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `material-ui` folder should be in `node_modules`

Delete your `material-ui` folder and run `npm install material-ui`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I must say that I really have forgotten about that, thanks :)

Comment: I've got one more question. I'm also trying to import a react-tap-event-plugin. So I've got it in a node-modules folder but I'm still getting error.

Comment: `npm install react-tap-event-plugin` then follow these lines : https://github.com/callemall/material-ui#react-tap-event-plugin

Comment: MuiThemeProvider was moved to core/styles: `import MuiThemeProvider from '@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider';`

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by installing new version:

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/core@next

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/core@next
```